# why is ngDoCheck() being called when i have called detach() from ChangeDetectorRef?

Tags: angular, observable, angular-changedetection

I was going through some articles on change detection and i was trying to enable or disable change detection using the `changeDetectorRef.detach()` and `changeDetectorRef.reattach()` .

I also hooked the component to the `ngDoCheck()` only to find `ngDoCheck()` being called even after `detach()` . 
What am i doing wrong ? Can someone explain why `ngDocheck()` is called ?
I have even the `ChangeDetectionStartegy` set to `OnPush` too . 
 [This is the article i was going through to understand change detection](https://juristr.com/blog/2017/03/angular-tuning-change-detection/)

I have also created an example for this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ytdbs

Comment: Answer  : https://blog.angularindepth.com/if-you-think-ngdocheck-means-your-component-is-being-checked-read-this-article-36ce63a3f3e5

Comment: @selemmn the article doesn't not mention anything about ``changeDetectorRef.detach()`` and how ``ngDoCheck()`` behaves or change detection behaves due to this :(

Answer (score 0):

That's because `detach()` detaches the component from it's own `ChangeDetector`, making it not check the template/input/host bindings. This is a different thing than `ngDoCheck` is doing. This is used to implement a sort of custom change detection, for changes that you know will happen, but angular cannot anticipate on. It's called for any cycle anywhere in the application.

I suppose the only way to not have your code run inside your `ngDoCheck` is to set a flag when detaching:

```
ngDoCheck(): void {
  if (attached) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

But I'm sure you have figured that one out as well :)

The [link](https://blog.angularindepth.com/if-you-think-ngdocheck-means-your-component-is-being-checked-read-this-article-36ce63a3f3e5) provided by @selemmn really gives a good insight

Comment: the official docs says that ngDoCheck() is called after every change detection cycle . But here I've detached the ``changeDetector`` , so change detection shouldn't be called until it is reattached , so ``ngDoCheck()`` shouldn't be called right ? or am i missing something here ?

Comment: @CruelEngine your interpretation is wrong. A change detection cycle is a `tick()` from `ApplicationRef`. This is always called, regardless of your components change detector settings. `NgDoCheck` is not a part of the components changeDetector, but is a custom change detection implementation. This will always be called

Comment: i created another example to understand the working of ``ngDoCheck()`` in the similar way . ``ngDoCheck()`` is being called only after 5 seconds when ``ref.reattach()`` is called . Stackblitz link :   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r2zlev

Comment: in your example it's called at the same time. Not because of the reattach, but because the setInterval got triggered. This will trigger a `tick` throughout the application